# Cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#

```
public class Account
{
}
public class SpecificationBase<T>
{
}
public class AccountSearch : SpecificationBase<Account>
{
}
public class SearchBase<T> where T : SpecificationBase<T>
{
}
public class Start
{
    public Start()
    {
        new SearchBase<AccountSearch>();
    }
}
```

> Error: The type '`AccountSearch`' cannot be used as type parameter '`T`' in the generic type or method '`SearchBase<T>`'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '`AccountSearch`' to '`SpecificationBase<AccountSearch>`'

Comment: which is your question?, fixing the error for you? Did you read about generic in C#?, you can press F1 over the error and you will be redirected to the MSDN with a full explination of that error

Comment: What exactly is the question? The error message seems to be pretty clear on what your problem is...

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are factually correct and will make the issue go away, I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
public class Account
{
}
public class SpecificationBase<T>
{
}
public class AccountSearch : SpecificationBase<Account>
{
}
public class SearchBase<T, TModel> where T : SpecificationBase<TModel>
{
}
public class Start
{
    public Start()
    {
        new SearchBase<AccountSearch, Account>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explained. Change the restriction to concrete type to perform valid conversion:

```
public class Account
{
}
public class SpecificationBase<T>
{
}
public class AccountSearch : SpecificationBase<Account>
{
}
public class SearchBase<T> where T : SpecificationBase<Account>
{
}
public class Start
{
    public Start()
    {
        new SearchBase<AccountSearch>();
    }
}
```

}